# Office Template wrong path hangs the document opening

Tags: microsoft-office, templates

When sending our clients a document based on a template, they get the following screen:

[image]

Wrong path

It takes about 10 minutes until the document finally opens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with using pics from the server.
After copy-pasting them sideways and back in this annoying thing went away.